# Make div and all its children ignore parent class styles

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

I am making an application that takes html as input to a text area and that input is then sent as an email to a recipient. I want to add a preview feature that will render the html as it would appear when received in an email so I need to be able to render this text without any effect from parent styles. Essentially I need to take a string holding html and render it in an angular application as if it were its own independent html file. Is there a way to make it so everything inside a div and all its children completely ignore all exterior styles? Right now I am rendering the html from a string this way (emailBodyHtml is just a string containing input html):

```html
<div [innerHTML]="emailBodyHtml"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a separate component and encapsulate using `ViewEncapsulation.Native` or `ViewEncapsulation.Emulated` which will help wrap the styles to that component. [StackBlitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-odxykx).

I have used `Native` to get this as a shadow dom element which is totally isolated from your other dom styles.

**component.ts**

```
import { Component, Input, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: `<div [innerHTML]="emailBodyHtml"></div>`,
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.Native
})
export class HelloComponent  {
  @Input() emailBodyHtml: string;
}
```